# Primary key of a relation with circular functional dependencies

Tags: database, circular-dependency, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I'm studying for my database exam and I'm not sure about one question which goes as follow:

> Given the relation R={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I} and the set of functional dependencies
>
> F = { AB -> C,
>
> A -> DE,
>
> C -> AB,
>
> B -> FGH,
>
> D -> IJ,
>
> D -> CBE
> }
>
> Under what (normal) form is this relation?

First, I know I have to find all candidate keys. Looking at the right, I see that every attribute of R appears on the right hand-side, so it is not trivial that any single attribute of R is a candidate key. So looking at the left hand-size, only A, B, C, D appear, so one or some of these attributes must appear in the candidate keys.

So using A, C and D works (details skipped), but using B alone doesn't. Considering using two-attribute ket is useless since any key that does not contain A, C or D won't "bring us back" to R. Exemple, BE allows us to find B, E, F, G, H, but then we can't proceed further, so not all attributes of R are found.

Also, using any combination with A, C, or D in it is useless since it contains a subset (a single attribute) which is part of a candidate key (a single attribute). Example, AB can be reduced to A, and then all attributes of R can be found.

What bugs me is AB -> C and C -> AB, which is a circular dependency. I thought of two possibilities:

1. C is the primary key and we can use it to find A and B (C -> AB);
2. AB can be reduced to A (as said above) and with it we can find C.

But it is very easy to see that AB must be unique and C must also be unique.

Let's only use AB -> C. We can have the following associations:

> 11 -> 1 (A = 1, B = 1, C = 1)
>
> 12 -> 1

But then, if we reinsert the rule C -> AB, we find:

> 1 -> 11
>
> 1 -> 12

which can't hold.

So C has to be unique.

Same thing if we only consider C -> AB, and then reinsert the rule AB -> C.

I'm starting to think that this is a trick and that the real primary key of this relation is ABC to ensure uniqueness of the combinations of AB and C. We would then have the following rules:

> F'={
>
> ABC -> DEFGH
>
> D -> IJ
>
> D -> CBE
>
> }

Is this right? What about the other circular dependency, i.e. C -> D (first rule), D -> C (third rule), and C -> D (going back to first rule)? Do I simply not care about it?

If I don't care about it (and assuming the primary key is ABC), then it seems obvious that this table is not in 3NF since ABC determines D (which is a non prime attribute here), and D determines IJ, two non prime attributes. But it seems to be in 2NF because no non prime attribute (D, E, F, G, H, I, J) can be obtain using a subset of attributes of the candidate keys (ABC here).

Of course, I could consider the primary key to be A, C or D and split AB -> C and C -> AB in two separate relations, but I don't think joining those two tables will always respect the rules AB -> C and C -> AB. For example, if someone inserts a new row in one of the table, then the join could introduce an invalid row.

I am thinking too much? Am I going in the wrong direction?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I don't miss school.

Answer (score 1):

```
AB -> C
A -> DE
C -> AB
B -> FGH
D -> IJ
D -> CBE
```

I will assume that the FDs in your relation are known to be exactly those in the the transitive closure of F. (What were you actually told about F vis a vis your relation?)

{} only determines trivially.

{A} determines DE, which determines IJCB, which determines FGH. CK.
{B} determines FGH. Not CK.
{C} determines AB. CK.
{D} determines IJCBE. CK.
Other singleton sets just determine trivially.

Proper supersets of A, C and D are not CKs.
Other proper supersets are of B,E,F,G,H,I,J, which cannot determine A, C or D. Not CKs.

That accounts for all subsets of attributes.
So the CKs are {A},{B} and {D}.

> What bugs me is AB -> C and C -> AB, which is a circular dependency.

Why should this bug you? Just follow the rules you were given. Review the definition of CK and how to determine the CKs from FDs. Eschew non-technical terms.

> the real primary key of this relation

"Primary key" is not a useful notion in normalization. (I can't make much sense of what follows.)

> this table is not in 3NF since

I don't see any definition of 3NF being used in your reasoning. You seem to use a definition of BCNF, but not properly.

> assuming the primary key is ABC
>   the candidate keys (ABC here)

Make up your mind. Is there one candidate key {A,B,C} or three candidate keys {A}, {B} and {C}? This is two different situations.

> it seems to be in 2NF because no non prime attribute [...] can be obtain using a subset of attributes of the candidate keys

You mean no non-prime attribute is functionally dependent on a proper subset of attributes of any candidate key. You misquoted, then misused what you quoted as if it meant what you should have quoted.

Review the definitions of the normal forms and the definitions they depend on.